# Adjusting the overlapping percentage numbers in a bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I want to achieve that the percentage numbers don't overlap like in the diagramm of this example ([Link to Example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550692/showing-percentage-in-multiple-horizontal-stacked-bars)) So the numbers should be in a space between A and B (preferably respectively ahead of the bar). In addition, I want all the numbers on top of the chart (I think it looks nicer.):

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{testbar3/.style={
        xbar stacked,
        width=.8\textwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {B,A},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        bar width=6mm, y=8mm,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, % <-- prints % sign after y coordinate value
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        nodes near coords align={center}, % <-- horizontal alignment centered of nodes 
        enlarge y limits=0.5, % <-- Adds vertical space so to not crop the bars
}}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[testbar3, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.6)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}
            ]
            \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};
            \legend{A,B,A\textsubscript{1},B\textsubscript{1},A\textsubscript{2},C}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Vergleich der prozentualen Ausdehnung:\\ A, B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Adjusted chart:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{testbar3/.style={
        xbar stacked,
        width=.8\textwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {B,A},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        bar width=6mm, y=16mm,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, % <-- prints % sign after y coordinate value
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        nodes near coords align={center}, % <-- horizontal alignment centered of nodes 
        enlarge y limits=0.75, % <-- Adds vertical space so to not crop the bars
}}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[testbar3, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.22)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}, every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.5cm}
            ]
            \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};
            \legend{A,B,A\textsubscript{1},B\textsubscript{1},A\textsubscript{2},\textit{Coda}}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Vergleich der prozentualen Ausdehnung:\\ A, B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Needed changes]

Comment: You could add `every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.5cm},` to the option list of the `axis` . And you probably need to increase the space between the bars with something like `y=15mm` instead of `y=8mm` in the options you set via `\pgfplotsset`.

Comment: And, "Neutral" should be capitalized.  Not exactly Tikz, but my editor-eye couldn't resist.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks for your answer. I adjusted the graph. It goes in the right direction, but I need a way to shift especially the last two percentage numbers in way that they don't overlap. Also, it would be nice to adjust the spaces the bars an the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution shifts up or down selected `nodes near coords`

[image: x]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{,
    xmin=0,
    /tikz/font=\footnotesize,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=85pt,
        width=\axisdefaultwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        x post scale=1.3,   
        scale only axis,
        enlarge y limits=0.75, 
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=6mm, y=14mm,
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
        nodes near coords style={
            yshift={
                ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 5,\plotnum == 2) , -13pt,13pt)
            }
             }, % shift down the third and sixth node       
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,font=\normalsize},
        ]
           \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};
            \legend{A,B,A\textsubscript{1},B\textsubscript{1},A\textsubscript{2},\textit{Coda}}     
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{Vergleich der prozentualen Ausdehnung:  A, B}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```